# Find a root of trigonmetric funtion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

Let $\ell \in [0, 1).$  Assume that $g(s)=\sin(s+x(s))-\ell \sin(x(s))=0$ and $\cos(x(0)) \neq 0.$

Is it true that if $s=0$, then  $x(0)=\pi$?( Im interested in answers in $[0, \pi]$).

Attempt: $g'(s)=\cos(s+x(s))(1+x'(s))-\ell\cos(x(s))x'(s)=0$. Since $s=0$, $\cos(x(0))(1+x'(0))-\ell\cos(x(0))x'(0)=0$. Then, $x'(0)(-\ell +1)+1=0$. Then$ x'(0)=\frac{-1}{1-\ell}.$

By Taylor expansion, $x(s) \approx \pi- \frac{1}{\ell -1}s$, where $\ell=\ell(s).$

Comment: I'd avoid using differentiation to solve the problem since assuming $x(s)$ to be differentiable seems unnecessarily restrictive. Instead, approach the problem like one would a typical functional equation, with substitution of values, algebraic manipulation, and properties of functions, as Suzu_Hirose has done. I would agree with your value of $x'(0)$ if you can assume it to exist, but $x(0)$ is not necessarily $\pi$.

Comment: @Jam Thank you for your comment. Are you saying that $x(0)$ can be zero? I am interested in the answer between $[0, \pi].$

Comment: Result for $x(0)$ depends on requirement. If $x(s)$ is required to be inside $[0,\pi]$ at small positive $s$, then $x(0)=0$ is correct. If $x(s)$ is required to be inside $[0,\pi]$ at small negative $s$, then $x(0)=\pi$ is correct. If there is no requirement on $x(s)$ only on $x(0)\in[0,\pi]$ then both answers are correct.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you for your comment. Why $x(0)=\pi$ for small negative $s$?

Comment: For small negative $s$: $x(s)\approx x(0)+\frac{s}{1-l} < x(0)$.  If $x(0)\leq 0$, then $x(s)<0$ which contradicts to $x(s)\in[0,\pi]$. Then $x(0)=\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\ell \in [0, 1).$  Assume that $g(s)=\sin(s+x(s))-\ell \sin(x(s))=0$ and $\cos(x(0)) \neq 0.$

> Is it true that if $s=0$, then  $x(0)=0\text{ or } \pi$?

If $s=0$ then $g(0)=\sin(x(0))-\ell\sin(x(0))=(1-\ell)\sin(x(0))=0$
and we know that $1-\ell \neq0$ so it must be that $\sin(x(0))=0$ so $x(0)=n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! $x(s)$ can not be zero, right? As I explained in the attempt

Comment: I think $x(s)$ can be zero, what conditions forbid that? In my answer $n$ can be $0$ since it is any integer ($n\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: You meant $x(0)$, right? there is a minor error in the last part of your proof. Because $x(s) \approx \pi-\frac{1}{\ell -1}s.$

Comment: Yes I meant x(0) but I'm completely lost what you're asking.